# How to break URL's in java?

Tags: java

If I have a string:

```
This is a sentence. It also has a url www.example.com.
```

how can i break it, and turn it into

```
This is a sentence. It also has a url www example com.
```

notice the url was broken, but the other dots weren't removed.
how do i do this with java?

Comment: First, `www.example.com` is not a URL, it's a domain. `http://www.example.com` is a URL. There's no way to know which dot should be removed and which one shouldn't unless you know the structure of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expresion like this

```
/^www\.([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$/
```